# How to Add Icon/Marker to OSM Map using OpenLayers 4.6.4

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, markers

I wonder if someone can point me in the right direction. I'm trying to add multiple markers/icons to an OSM map using OpenLayers 4.6.4.

The following code renders the map without any problem:

```
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'mapdiv',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.1526069, 51.4790309]),
                zoom: 14
            })
        });
    </script>
```

I've tried searching on the OpenLayers website for information how to add a marker but it states markers are deprecated! All I want to do is add some pins/markers to the map to display site locations.

I've also tried other versions of OpenLayers 2.13.1, 2.14 and 3.0 without any success.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The old markers are deprecated. You should use geometry [Points](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Point-Point.html) with [Icon style](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Icon-Icon.html). [Icon Symbolizer Example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html) is the one you are looking for:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var iconFeature1 = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.1526069, 51.4790309]), ),
    name: 'Somewhere',
  });

  var iconFeature2 = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.1426069, 51.4840309])),
    name: 'Somewhere else'
  });

  // specific style for that one point
  iconFeature2.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 46],
      anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
      anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
      src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/93/Map_marker_font_awesome.svg/200px-Map_marker_font_awesome.svg.png',
    })
  }));




  const iconLayerSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [iconFeature1, iconFeature2]
  });

  const iconLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: iconLayerSource,
    // style for all elements on a layer
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/examples/data/icon.png'
      })
    })
  });


  const map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      }),
      iconLayer
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.1526069, 51.4790309]),
      zoom: 14
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol-debug.js"></script>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and guidance, dude. Much appreciated.